# Make css dropdown menu items not overlap parent item

Tags: html, css

I'm making a basic website with a language switcher dropdown but I'm having a problem that the dropdown items overlap the active dropdown item as shown below. How can I remove this overlap?

[image]

[image]

The code for this example:

```css
/* Language switcher */

.lang-switch-hidden {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    width: auto;
}

.lang-switch-hidden {
    display: none !important;
    position: absolute;
}

li#lang-switch-active-lang {
    padding: 10px 16px;
}

li#lang-switch-active-lang:hover>.lang-switch-hidden {
    display: block !important;
}

li.lang-switch-active-lang,
li.lang-switch-inactive-lang {
    display: list-item !important;
}

/* Navigation bar */

#navbar {
    color: black;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    margin-top: 1.5em;
}

#navbar ul {
    display: table;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

/* right and left aligned trick http://jsfiddle.net/QfD6J/7/ */

#navbar li {
    display: table-cell;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

#menuleft-last {
    width: 100%;
}

#navbar a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    padding: 10px 16px;
}

#navbar b {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px 16px;
}

#navbar a:hover {
    background-color: #dfdfdf;
}

.dropdown {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="navbar">
  <ul>
    <li class="" id="menuleft-last">
      <a href="#">Home</a>
    </li>

    <li><b>Projects:</b></li>
    <li class="">
      <a href="project1">Project 1</a>
    </li>

    <li class="">
      <a href="project2">Project 2</a>
    </li>

    <li id="lang-switch-active-lang"><img src="https://mattiasjohnson.com/flags/English.svg" width="20em" /> <i style="  border: solid black;
        border-width: 0 2px 2px 0;
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 3px;
        transform: rotate(45deg);
        -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);"></i>
      <ul class="lang-switch-hidden">

        <li class="lang-switch-inactive-lang"><a title="Italian" href="">
            <img src="https://mattiasjohnson.com/flags/Italian.svg" width="20em" />
          </a>
        </li>

      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

`.`

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 0):

```
.lang-switch-hidden {
    display: none !important;
    position: absolute;
    top: 62px;
    right: 2px;
}
```